# How can a low level adventurer magically disguise an item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, equipment

I have a character who is bound to a certain set of wind chimes, which they can't be separated from for long due to plot-related reasons. However, these wind chimes are very valuable to some very sketchy people, and my possession of it puts my character in constant danger.

While hiding this item on my person will work most of the time (taped or strung together, to avoid making a sound), it will be unavoidable that I will have to take it out in the open for others to see. There may also be times that I won't have the item on my person. Due to the high degree of danger of even taking this item out, in both cases, I would like the item to be visually hidden.

The essence of what I want to do is cast a “*disguise self*”-like effect on these wind chimes, so that it is disguised in the same way a creature would be — that is, if the chimes were a creature that could cast *disguise self*, that would be perfect. Of course, the chimes are inanimate, so this solution is not viable. Is there another way I can achieve this?

When the item is held, the one who holds it will probably learn there's an illusion on the thing, but onlookers wouldn't know unless they held or inspected the item themselves.

I don't have access to 3rd level spells or higher. What spells, abilities, items, or other effects can produce what I want?

If a high level spell or rare item *can* do what I want, it's still useful to mention it. I just wouldn't have access to that, but I would know to watch out for it.

Comment: To clarify, is the intent here that the item can be passed around and maintain its disguise (as opposed to Disguise Self, which affects the caster)?

Comment: @Kommissar Ideally, the disguise over the item can be maintained even if different people hold it.

Comment: You do have access to only second level spells and lower, and no magic items.  Right?   Saying what you "don't have" is partly useful in the question, but clarifying exactly what you *do* have would be better.

Answer (score 13):

### Disguise Self can do this

The spell description says

> You make yourself — including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person — look different

So while you are wielding the item, this item can be disguised.

Disguise Self works only on the caster and their equipment. If you want to change an appearance of an item wielded by another creature, you need a higher level spell.

### Seeming spell can do more

The 5th-level illusion spell *Seeming* can change the appearance of other creature's equipment:

> This spell allows you to change the appearance of any number of creatures that you can see within range. You give each target you choose a new, illusory appearance.
>
> The spell disguises physical appearance as well as clothing, armor, weapons, and equipment.

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't it make more sense to disguise it by non-magical means? Pay a reasonable amount to a carpenter or other craftsperson to create an item that cleverly hides the chimes within it. Think of the example of a sword-cane or spy devices hidden in shoes, clothing or other personal effects. You mention taping or tying it to your body - why not go a step further and have it made into part of a set of splint mail armor, or sandwiched between layers of a shield (with some of those layers being thin sheets of lead)?

Comment: I always favor non-magical means. This is an awesome response